# OwlCarousel 2 function animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, owl-carousel

I'm using owl.carousel 2 (beta version). The animate function for fade effect works only clicking on nav buttons. Is there a function (or add a code) that changes the images when I click on the image? So I can hide prev-next buttons. Thanks.

Comment: please post a code or fiddle so we can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like this:

```
var owl=$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    loop:true,
    margin:10
}).click(function(){
    owl.trigger('next.owl.carousel');
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sm6nc81z/2/